# Laravel MySQL SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

So I have been trying to get an connection my database with homestead, but everytime I make a DB select statement I get an SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused. It seems like my problem is not the same as the others with the same title. I am using homestead with virtual box

Here is my select statement:

```
   <?php
         echo DB::select('select * from bruger where id = 1')
    ?>;
```

This is simply to check if I can get any info out.

I have tried various things in both my .env file and and database.php

This is what they are looking like currently:

```
  'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

and

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=randomKey
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=phpDatabase
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=secret
REDIS_PORT=33060

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: 'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost'),
should be         'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),

Comment: Already tried that.. Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port should be 3306, since you are accessing from within the homestead machine, if I understood correctly.

In fact, check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#connecting-to-databases)

> You will use the default 3306 and 5432 ports in your Laravel database configuration file since Laravel is running within the virtual machine.

Comment: Okay this gave me an array to string conversion error, but this should managable. Thanks

Comment: That's for attempting to `echo` the result of the DB query. You can try functions `print_r` or `dd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For DB_HOST and DB_PORT try using the IP and port as set in the Homestead.yaml file.

Default:
`DB_HOST=192.168.10.10`
`DB_PORT=3306`